# Using Radio to find higher SPECIAL dwellers

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have several high charisma dwellers in the radio finding dwellers, I can find like 1 everyday, the problem is that their SPECIAL is really low, if I use high stat dwellers, will I find high stat dwellers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a dweller with high charisma is all that matters. The higher the charisma, the bigger the chances of getting dwellers. Also, having a dweller with good SPECIAL stats in the Radio Studio doesn't increase the chances of getting a dweller with better SPECIAL stats.